# Problem in importing User define packages with in a jsp page

Tags: jsp

I am gurpreet and i m developed a web application and i want to import a User Define packge with my *.jsp file. but when im importing file using

`<%@page import="Package.Dit"%>`

it shows an error/warning message "Package doesnot exist."

thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have a compiled class called `Dit` in a package called `Package`? My guess is that you do not, or that the compiler reads `Package` as a reserved word and gives the error. Try to change your class from `Package` to `mypackage`.